# Execution order of global variable destructor and gcc attribute__((destructor))

Tags: c++, gcc, static, destructor, destruction

This is a GCC specific issue. I'm encountering a werid issue in a .so library. The demo code of this .so library could be:

```cpp
__attribute__((init_priority(101))) std::unique_ptr<object_t> global_object;

__attribute__((constructor)) void entry_constructor() {
    global_object = make_unique<object_t>();
}

__attribute__((destructor)) void entry_destructor() {
    global_object.reset(nullptr);
}
```

I know the global `global_object` would be released automatically even without `entry_destructor`. But I just want to give you an example. For debug building, the `entry_destructor` runs well. But for release building, it crashed.

I set break points and debugged this issue. In debug build, the `entry_destructor` is executed firstly, then runs `std::unique_ptr::destructor`. But in release build, the `std::unique_ptr::destructor` is run before `entry_destructor`.

Firstly hit here:

```cpp
#3  std::unique_ptr<...> >::~unique_ptr (this=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:263
#4  0x00007ffff5b8c0f1 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x7ffff5f34718 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true, run_dtors=run_dtors@entry=true) at exit.c:108
#5  0x00007ffff5b8c1ea in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:139
#6  0x00007ffff5b6ab9e in __libc_start_main (main=0x555555672c51 <main(int, char**)>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2b8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe2a8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:344
#7  0x000055555566eb0a in _start ()
```

Then hit here:

```cpp
#3  std::unique_ptr<...>::reset (__p=0x555555893ae0, this=0x55555585bc70 <...>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:371
#5  0x000055555567b021 in entry_destructor () at ...
#6  0x00007ffff7de5bc3 in _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:138
#7  0x00007ffff5b8c0f1 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x7ffff5f34718 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true, run_dtors=run_dtors@entry=true) at exit.c:108
#8  0x00007ffff5b8c1ea in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:139
#9  0x00007ffff5b6ab9e in __libc_start_main (main=0x555555672c51 <main(int, char**)>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2b8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe2a8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:344
#10 0x000055555566eb0a in _start ()
```

I marked `global_object` as `__attribute__((init_priority(101)))` because only by that it can be initialized before `entry_construtor`, otherwise `entry_contructor` would crash when accessing `global_object`.

I also tried to mark `global_object` as `static`, but it didn't help either.

I hope all global variables should be destructed after `entry_destructor`, whether it's debug build or release build. All the documents and discussions I can find are about the construt and destruct order or global variables, but not the order between global variable destruct and `__attribute__((destructor))`. Is there any GCC rule for that? Or is it an undefined behavior?

Comment: Nobody cares...